# wait to open com port on button event in Java instead of console entered port selection

Tags: java, swing, serial-port, event-listener

Below is the code I am using to open a com port - it waits for a user input number from the console scanner to open the port which is listed in a JComboBox. I have an event listener with a button which I want to use to open the com port instead. But I'm not sure of a best practice to 'stop' further execution until the user presses the button to open the port. (the console scanner is conveniently allowing the program to wait for the selection at the moment). I just want the program to only proceed when a port is opened after a press.
A jcombo box has the ports displayed and I can obtain the port number using getSelectedIndex()

```
package testPackage;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ItemSelectable;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;
import javax.swing.*;


//To test - Select option 5, from select a port dialogue (Com0Com port 6)
//open terminal program - select port Com0Com 7 
//send numbers as Ascii
public class Main {
static SerialPort serialPort; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Window1 window1 = new Window1();
        JComboBox<String> commList = new JComboBox<>();
        window1.add(commList);  
        JButton bigButton = new JButton("Select Comm port");
        window1.add(bigButton);

        window1.pack();
        window1.setVisible(true);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("My label");
        window1.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();

        System.out.println("Select a port:");
        int i = 1;
        for(SerialPort port : ports) {
            System.out.println(i++ +  ": " + port.getSystemPortName());
            commList.addItem(port.getSystemPortName());
        }

        bigButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Clicked");
                label.setText("Selected");
                   System.out.println("Selected: " + commList.getSelectedItem());
                   System.out.println("Position: " + commList.getSelectedIndex());  
                  // SerialPort serialPort = ports[commList.getSelectedIndex()];
                   open_serial();
            }

            private void open_serial() {
                 serialPort = ports[commList.getSelectedIndex()];


            }

        });     

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int chosenPort = s.nextInt();
        SerialPort serialPort = ports[chosenPort - 1];
//      System.out.println("Chosen port : " + chosenPort);
//        System.out.println("Selected: " + commList.getSelectedItem());
//        System.out.println("Position: " + commList.getSelectedIndex());
        if(serialPort.openPort())
            System.out.println("Port opened successfully.");
        else {
            System.out.println("Unable to open the port.");
            s.close();
            return;
        }   
        serialPort.setBaudRate(9600);
        serialPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, 0, 0);
        Scanner data = new Scanner(serialPort.getInputStream());
        int value = 0;
        //Thread thread = new Thread();
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(serialPort.getOutputStream());

            output.print("Hiya"); 
            output.flush();
            System.out.println("printing1");



        while(data.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(value);
            try{value = Integer.parseInt(data.nextLine());}catch(Exception e){}
            output.print("Received"); 
            output.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");
        data.close();
        s.close();

    }

};

//-here is the window1 class
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Window1 extends JFrame{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JButton BigButton;


public Window1() {
    super("Programmer");
    setLookAndFeel();
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
    setLayout(flo);

    setVisible(true);  
}


private void setLookAndFeel() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
        );
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        // ignore error
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Generally Scanner is not used when using Swing. And you shouldn't be using any sort of blocking I/O (like the serial port) on the main Swing update thread. It would be best to have a separate thread than handles the serial events.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm not sure of a best practice to 'stop' further execution until the user presses the button to open the port.

I can think of two main ways to "pause" a Swing GUI while awaiting user input:

1. If the program should fully stop, then put the port selection into a model dialog, such as either a JOptionPane or the more general modal JDialog. This prevents the calling code, the main GUI, from interacting with the user until the dialog is no longer visible (has been handled), or
2. Use a state-design pattern type of program where you simply don't respond to user input until the port has been selected, such as by having if blocks located where the user might interact, that checks the state of port selection and only handles the user interaction until the port selection is valid. For example, you could have a variable, `SerialPort selectedPort = null;` and elsewhere in your other listeners, the ones not involved with port selection, have at the top: `if (selectedPort == null) { return; }`

If you would like further details, then consider creating and posting a valid [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question, and I can help adapt it to your needs. Please check out the link to this valuable tool.

---

Here is an example of what I meant. Run it to try it out.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyPortExample extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea fromPortArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
    private Action sendAction = new SendAction("Send");
    private Action setUpPortAction = new SetUpPortAction("Set Up Port", this);
    private JTextField toPortField = new JTextField(35);
    private JTextField portNameField = new JTextField(15);
    private JButton sendTextBtn = new JButton(sendAction);
    private PrintStream outFromPort = null;
    private MockSerialPort serialPort = null;

    public MyPortExample() {
        portNameField.setFocusable(false);
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(new JButton(setUpPortAction));
        topPanel.add(portNameField);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(fromPortArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        sendAction.setEnabled(false);
        toPortField.setAction(sendAction);
        fromPortArea.setFocusable(false);

        JPanel sendPanel = new JPanel();
        sendPanel.add(toPortField);
        sendPanel.add(sendTextBtn);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(scrollPane);
        add(sendPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void setSerialPort(MockSerialPort port) {
        this.serialPort = port;
        outFromPort = (PrintStream) port.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = port.getInputStream();
        new PortWorker(in, fromPortArea).execute();
        portNameField.setText(port.getSystemPortName());
        sendAction.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public MockSerialPort getSerialPort() {
        return serialPort;
    }

    private class PortWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
        private Scanner portScanner;
        private JTextArea textArea;

        public PortWorker(InputStream in, JTextArea fromPortArea) {
            this.textArea = fromPortArea;
            portScanner = new Scanner(in);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            while (portScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                publish(portScanner.nextLine());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String text : chunks) {
                textArea.append(text + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    private class SendAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SendAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (outFromPort != null) {
                String text = toPortField.getText();
                outFromPort.println(text);
                toPortField.selectAll();
                toPortField.requestFocusInWindow();
            } else {
                System.err.println("No output stream available");
            }
        }

    }

    private static class SetUpPortAction extends AbstractAction {
        private MyPortExample myPortExample;

        public SetUpPortAction(String name, MyPortExample myPortExample) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_P);
            this.myPortExample = myPortExample;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int messageType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
            MockSerialPort port = (MockSerialPort) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(myPortExample, "Please select a port",
                    "Port Selection", messageType, null, MockSerialPort.getCommPorts(), null);
            if (port != null) {
                myPortExample.setSerialPort(port);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyPortExample mainPanel = new MyPortExample();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyPortExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MockSerialPort {

        public static final String TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING = "timeout read semi blocking";
        private String portName;
        private int baudRate;

        public MockSerialPort(String name) {
            this.portName = name;
        }

        public String getSystemPortName() {
            return portName;
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
            return System.out;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() {
            return System.in;
        }

        public void setComPortTimeouts(String timeoutReadSemiBlocking, int i, int j) {
            // TODO ??? not sure what goes here
        }

        public void setBaudRate(int baudRate) {
            this.baudRate = baudRate;
        }

        public boolean openPort() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return portName;
        }

        public static MockSerialPort[] getCommPorts() {
            List<MockSerialPort> ports = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                ports.add(new MockSerialPort("Port " + (i + 1)));
            }
            return ports.toArray(new MockSerialPort[] {});
        }
    }
}
```

The GUI is disabled until a port is selected via the button on the top, then the JTextField and button on the bottom are enabled to send data to the port via `.setEnabled(true)`.

This also contains a "mock" class for the serial port class which I do not have.

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply. Are you suggesting that I should post the rest of the code and you have a look?

Comment: @Russell: No, not all the code, since my guess is that it is a large program, likely too large to be allowed here in its entirety, and containing a lot of code completely unrelated to your problem at hand. No, I'm suggesting that you create a new program, again, a [mre]. Again, the link will explain what it is that I'm suggesting, how to create one and how it can help you. It should be small enough to post in your question as code-formatted text in its entirety, and we should be able to copy-paste-compile and run it without alteration.

Comment: Hi - the code is not very long as I have really just started - there is main class and a  class to do the window GUI - the present code is just to open a comm port using button instead of console entry

Comment: Further - excuse my ignorance, but where would I send my code as I am now only seeing a comments response option - or should I edit the original code. Apologies, am learning

Comment: @Russell: you [edit your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61760492/edit) and post it there.

Comment: ok done - This is the main class. There is a shorter window class for the gui, which I could add too, then it should be able to be run

Comment: Won't compile for me due to missing dependences, including `Window1` and `import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;` Need to show the first, and create a "mock" class for the second since your code needs to be compilable and runnable by us without our needing to modify it.

Comment: Hi - I have added the Window1 class now

Comment: Not to sure about the 'mock' class - you mean all in one file ready to run - I will try

Comment: Ok -I think the present code is the best I can do for now. Any suggestions would be great

Comment: @Russell: please see the example that I posted. Note that the GUI has an AbstractAction that is used by a JButton and a JTextField both, that is disabled initially via `.setEnabled(false)`, that a port is selected from within a JOptionPane, and that then the button's action is re-enabled.

Comment: @Russell: I threw other stuff in there, including using a SwingWorker to get text from the port, since if you did this in the GUI event thread, you'd block it and render your GUI useless.

Comment: HI - I ran it. It looks great and I see the Send button is only active after Set Up Port has been set. Thanks for the help. I added this to my code as a blocking statement - not sure if this non-preffered coding:    while (!port_selected) {}; // wait here until button clicked. I will use your ideas. Thanks again